# .htaccess - Change URL part to parameter and ignore the rest

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm doing SEO optimization for a website and I need to transform a part of the url into a parameter. The URL format can still be changed if needed.

Basically I'm working with Wordpress and want to create a single page that would work for all products, but I need to get a specific product number from the URL.

The URL looks something like this:

```
www.example.com/product/[product-id]-brand-name-and-some-other-stuff
```

I want to transform the URL behind the scenes (meaning the URL won't change) to this:

```
www.example.com/product/?pid=[product-id]
```

I don't have much experience with htaccess and any help would be appreciated.

Here's the current htaccess file's content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /downloads/www.bqwatches.com/

RewriteRule ^watch/([^-]+)- watch/?bqn=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /downloads/www.bqwatches.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What is your product-id? Is it just a number? For example, the URL would be `www.example.com/product/7134-some-kind-of-thing`?

Comment: There are two letters before the number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule just below `RewriteBase` line of your regular wordpress .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^watch/([^-]+)- watch/?pid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Tried this, but I couldn't get it to work yet. It's probably because the page is not directly in the root directory. How do I change it to work if I have, for example "site1/site2/" before the "/product" part ?

Comment: P.S., I'm putting it between WP's RewriteBase (in this case it would be "site1/site2/" and the first RewriteRule RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

Comment: what is your full URI and where exactly is Wordpress root?

Comment: Here's the URL to the site which displays the product number. http://londoncreativedigital.com/downloads/www.bqwatches.com/watch/?bqn=123
This one should do the same, but it doesn't
http://londoncreativedigital.com/downloads/www.bqwatches.com/watch/bq123-rolex-black

Comment: Here's the rule I'm using RewriteRule downloads/www.bqwatches.com/watch/([^-]+)- /downloads/www.bqwatches.com/watch/?bqn=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: Ok got it and where is your WP root? Is WP content served directly from DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Ok can you dump /downloads/www.bqwatches.com/.htaccess in your question?

Comment: Doesn't work... if you visit the links above, you can see how it works.

Comment: Can you dump **modified** `/downloads/www.bqwatches.com/.htaccess` in your question?

Comment: Ok for testing can your make flags as: `RewriteRule ^watch/([^-]+)- watch/?bqn=$1 [R,L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: That is what I suspected and that's been my experience with Wordpress that it needs actual URI to be able to present a page. If you have mod_proxy enabled this should also work: `RewriteRule ^watch/([^-]+)- watch/?bqn=$1 [P,L,QSA,NC]` if it's not available then we are out of luck as URL will indeed need to change so that WP can render the page.

Comment: It doesn't work with P. So if I enable mod_proxy, it should work, right ? Can I do it, or should I contact the admin about this?

Comment: It needs to be enabled via Apache config so you need to contact your admin for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Altered the solutions to account for the fact that a product id consists of two letters, then a number.

You do the following:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9]+).* product/?pid=$1
```

To explain what's happening, it matches the part after the URL that begins with `product/`, followed by two letters and several numbers, and then any other characters.  The letters-and-numbers get put into the `pid` parameter of the requested URL, and the rest is discarded.

If you pass it `http://www.example.com/product/af1234-some-product`, it converts behind-the-scenes to `http://www.example.com/product/?pid=af1234`.

You could also accept *any* two characters followed by a number, by doing the following:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(..[0-9]+).* product/?pid=$1
```

---

If the product id could be any character that *isn't* a `-`, then the following should achieve the same:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^-]+).* product/?pid=$1
```